# Openbox execute keybind

Tags: lubuntu, openbox

To adjust my backlight I'm using the command:

```
sudo bash -c "echo $backlight_value > /sys/class/backlight/apple_backlight/brightness;"
```

Now I want to setup a keybinding for the command above via shell script with openbox to adjust the backlight in my PC. To setup the keybinding I searched for the config file which is used by openbox:

```
 $ ps ax | grep openbox
 1194 ?        Sl     0:02 openbox --config-file /home/ubuntu/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml --sm-save-file /home/ubuntu/.cache/openbox/sessions/1478226066-1194-624962777.obs --sm-no-load
 1958 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto openbox
```

Next I edited the config file lubuntu-rc.xml and it works (I tested it):

```
 <!-- My Keybindings -->
    <keybind key="0xC0">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>lxterminal</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
```

Now I want to execute my custom shell script below. But in my shell script there are two commands (line 2 and 5) which needs addional permissions. How can I run them as root?

```
#!/bin/bash
curr=`cat /sys/class/backlight/apple_backlight/brightness`
if [ $curr -gt 0 ]; then
   curr=$((curr - 1));
   echo $curr > /sys/class/backlight/apple_backlight/brightness;
fi
```

I also changed privileges but the error is still there (permission denied):

```
ls -l /sys/class/backlight/apple_backlight/
total 0
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Nov  4 00:41 brightness
```

I tested only the script without binding and it works:

```
bash /home/ubuntu/Documents/CustomScripts/brightnessDown.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to setup the execution bit for both scripts:

```
-rw**x**r-**x**r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  189 Nov  4 15:34 brightnessDown.sh
-rw**x**r-**x**r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  191 Nov  4 15:36 brightnessUp.sh
```

So I entered:

```
sudo chmod 754 ~/Documents/CustomScripts/brightness*.sh
```

Now I can run both scripts via keyboard shortcuts.